# Resetting data in test environment

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

We have a test environment with an Oracle 12c DB. After running a series of application tests, we'd like to revert the database to its pre-test state (remove all of the test data).

What is the simplest way of achieving this?

Thanks,

Comment: Why don't you just delete the tablespace on which the test data is created?

Comment: You might consider flashback database: stackoverflow.com/questions/43613655/… The advantage is a much faster restore (since you won't be replacing everything... though, this is largely dependant on how much you are changing), but the downside is a moving window for your restore (as opposed to an RMAN backup that is point in time) and you should not perform non-logging operations since those operations aren't in the redo to replay during flashback database operations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest a backup and restore process.

Backup the Oracle DB in it's pristine state before you have ran your tests.
Then restore the database as required.

You can do this with Recovery Manager (RMAN)

See guide - https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmintro.htm#BRADV89334

Comment: Thank you. Is this preferable to dump & import? With a DB that's about 500GB, which one will be quicker?

Comment: I'm not too sure on the performance difference, however this explains the jist of the difference - https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30545/difference-between-database-dump-export-and-database-backup. Depending on whether you have data in the your "Pristine State" or not would probably be a factor in determining which one suits your needs.

Comment: I stand to be corrected, but I believe RMAN would be much faster

Comment: according to this source - http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_rman_export_expdp.htm RMAN is much faster and allows for parallel backup and restores.